# Azure VM unable to access port 8080

Tags: azure, npm, server, localhost, ip-address

I was following an online project tutorial. After an npm install command, the site was published according to the following output :  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://10.0.0.4:8080/

So to access it , I visited the following : https://publicipaddress:8080/
I opened port 8080 in the inbound rules as shown. Still the page does not connect and it times out.[image]

Comment: Could you show the tutorial links? Is there any firewall inside the Azure VM? Could you access the site via `http://publicipaddress:8080`?

Comment: Is the issue fixed on your side?